# C# Windows Service: Change Polling to Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduled-tasks, polling

I have created a C# Windows Service to poll(each one hour) and email with some attachments.
Everything is working fine.
Now, I want to convert the polling mechanism to a scheduler( like the program to be executed on 8.00, 12.00, 16.00 etc.)

Can I use the Services calss and Thread to do this? Or should I use timer and check the schedule time?
I am using the following logic now,

```
        do
        {

            PollingPass();

            // Next PollingPass() will execute after one hour.
            TimeSpan s = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(s);
        }
        while(1 == 1);
```

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but isn't a polling operation that takes places every hour not the same as a scheduled operation that is scheduled for each hour? Or am I missing something? It seems like if you make this 'every hour' a parameter in the service you get what you want.  What code are you using now to schedule the poll operation each hour?

Comment: Maybe you could the the built in Windows task scheduler? You can add it with Nuget.

Comment: @PeterBons Yes. If it is each one hour, it is like scheduler. But my new requirement is that the program should work at 8.00, 12.00 and 18.00 etc

Comment: I would always prefer a timer over blocking a thread, so yes, you could use a timer. Other option is to change it into a console app and use the windows scheduler.